# Writing and reading from the same file

Tags: c++, file

This program takes in an input, write it on a file character by character, count the amount of characters entered, then at the end copy it to an array of characters. The program works just fine until we get to the following snippet `file.getline(arr, inputLength);`. It changes the .txt file data and returns only the first character of the original input.

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int getLine(char *& arr);


int main() {
    char * arr = NULL;

    cout << "Write something: ";
    getLine(arr);
    return 0;
}


int getLine(char *& arr) {
    fstream file("temp.txt");
    char input = '\0'; //initialize
    int inputLength = 0; //initialize

    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (input != '\n') { //while the end of this line is not reached
            input = cin.get(); //get each single character
            file << input; //write it on a .txt file
            inputLength++; //count the number of characters entered
        }
        arr = new char[inputLength]; //dynamically allocate memory for this array
        file.getline(arr, inputLength); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!! ***
        cout << "Count : " << inputLength << endl; //test counter
        cout << "Array : " << arr << endl;         //test line copy
        file.close();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably about string is not being written in txt file. For right design, you should consider doing least IO on disks if possible. You should use memory and at the end write your data to txt file.

Comment: Would you explain that by using code snippets? @st.

Comment: Also, the data was written correctly on a txt file, only if you comment the line where the problem occurs. @st.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems with this code.

1) `std::fstream` constructor, by default, will open an existing file. It will not create a new one. If `temp.txt` does not exist, `is_open()` will fail. This code should pass the appropriate value for the second parameter to `std::fstream`s constructor that specifies that either a new file needs to be created, or the existing file is created.

Related to this: if the file already exists, running this code will not truncate it, so the contents of the file from this program's previous run will have obvious unexpected results.

2) The intent of this code appears to be to read back in the contents `temp.txt` that were previously written to it. To do that correctly, after writing and before reading it is necessary to seek back to the beginning of the file. This part appears to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in dynamic allocation because the std library functions get confused with mixed arguments such as cstring and pointer to cstring.I tested this code in Visual Studio 2015 compiler. It works good. Make sure to include all of the needed libraries:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include<cstring>
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;
  void getLine();
  int main() {

   cout << "Write something: ";

   // no need to pass a pointer to a cstring
   getLine();
   system("pause");
   return 0;
  }

     void getLine() {
      char input[100]; // this is a cstring with 
      //a safe const number of elements

      int inputLength; //to extract length of the actual input

      //this function requires cstring as a first argument
      // and constant length as a second
      cin.get(input, 100, '\n'); //get each single character

      //cast streamsize into int
     inputLength = static_cast<int>(cin.gcount());

    //testing input
    cout << "Input: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
     {
        cout << input[i];
     }

      cout << endl;

      char arr[100]; 

      strcpy_s(arr, input);

      cout << "Count : " << inputLength << endl; //test counter

      cout << "Array : " << endl;         //test line copy

      for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
      {
         cout << arr[i];
      }
       cout << endl;

        // write cstring to a file
       ofstream file;
       file.open("temp.txt", ios::out);
       if (file.is_open())
       {
            //write only what was entered in input
            for (int i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
            file << arr[i];
            file.close();
        }

              else cout << "Unable to open file";
     }
```